# Calculating limit of function composition

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose we know that 
$$
\exists \lim(h(x))_{x \to  x_0 -} = p \in \Bbb R
$$
$$
\exists \lim(s(t))_{t \to x_0-} = x_0
$$
Where $h(x), s(t)$ - functions with domain $D=(a,x_0)$. What is more, $s(t) \in  D \;\;  \forall t \in  D$. Can we assert the following:
$$
\exists \lim(h(s(t)))_{t \to x_0-} = p
$$
How to prove/disprove it rigorously in terms of $(ε, δ)$-definition of limits?

Comment: Hint: use the $\delta$ from the limit for $h$ as the $\epsilon$ in the limit for $s$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. By assumption there exists a $\delta_1>0$ such that $|h(x)-p|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in D$ with $0<x_0-x<\delta_1$. There also exists a $\delta_2>0$ such that $|s(x)-x_0|<\delta_1$ for all $x\in D$ with $0<x_0-x<\delta_2$. However, because $s(x)\in D$ for all $x$ this means that in fact $x_0-s(x)<\delta_1$ for all $x\in D$ with $0<x_0-x<\delta_2$.

Thus for all $x\in D$, such that $0<x_0-x<\delta_2$, we have $|h(s(x))-p|<\varepsilon$, because $0<x_0-s(x)<\delta_1$.